# Как добавить инерции мячу?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

В игре [Spin!](https://alienplay.itch.io/spin), мяч ведет себя буд-то пушинка, но в тоже время под гравитацией падает вниз набирая значительную скорость.

[image: Spin!]

Моя проблема в том, что мяч не отлетает от платформы, он буд-то прилипает к ней.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: массы добавить? гравитации убавить?

Comment: @aepot, масса НЕ ВЛИЯЕТ на скорость свободного падения, ни в игровой симуляции, ни в жизни, иначе луна рухнула бы на землю.

Comment: @Yaroslav я знаю, но сила, с которой толкается мячик, если он будет тяжелее или легче, даст емиу импульс больше или меньше

Comment: @aepot, масса имеет значение при столкновении, объекту меньшей массы пропорционально передается больший импульс силы, но только столкновении двух динамических объектов, а платформа статическая.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Игры с физикой

Дело в платформе, она не передает импульса силы мячу, потому что статическая. Мяч даже не подлетает в верх, только лишь гасит силу свободного падения, падая на платформу и находясь на ней, не более.

- Добавить платформе `Rigidbody`, установи `Freeze Positin`, отключить `Use Gravity` и установить `IsKinecatic`, что бы платформа не получала силу от взаимодействий, а вся сила передавалась мячу, не распределяясь долями согласно отношению масс тел. Мяч не сможет вращать платформу и платформа при вращении не будет получать долю силы в виде противодействия в обратную сторону, по сути забирая эту долю силы у мяча.
- Вращение через `Transform` только выталкивает мяч из нового положения платформы и все. Нужно придавать телу платформы `Angular Velocity` в `FixedUpdate`, что-бы её поворот стремился к соответствующему углу. **Физическое** вращение платформы будет предавать мячу силу, которая сможет отправлять его в полет.

Comment: Игры на физику никогда не делал, но должно работать.

Comment: Благодарю, это именно то чего не хватало. Платформа была у меня кинетической)

Comment: Если тело будет вращаться согласно `Angular Velocity` при `IsKinecatic`, то это ещё лучше! Я просто не знаю, нет опыта, в документации сказано что влияет **только** на столкновение. Тогда сила вообще никак не будет влиять на платформу и масса совсем становится не важна, вся сила что будет, все получит мяч, хотя это момент рекомендую потом потестить установив 1к2. 1к10, вдруг сила все же распределяется, но просто не применяется к кинетикам.

Comment: Если все с `IsKinecatic` работает корректно, то про возню с `Freeze Rotation` тоже можно забыть.

Comment: Да, сейчас проверил `IsKinecatic` работает корректно, осталось поработать с гравитацией. Благодарю, за помощь и пояснения.

Comment: До полемики с **@aepot**, не было представлений, как это делают, ответ пришел по ходу. И для чего нужно свойство `Kinecatic`, до того, как ты его упомянул, тоже не подозревал. Только понимал как работает физика взаимодействия тел. Сам узнал что-то новое, авось пригодится)